# Error 500: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, date, joomla

In Joomla component com_search I modified line from:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_date')) echo JText::sprintf('Published %s', $result->created).'. '; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_date')) echo '<span>'.JText::_('PUBLISHED').':     '.'</span>'.JText::sprintf('%s', JHtml::_('date',$result->created, JText::_('d. m. Y, H:i'))); ?>
```

and got error 500 when something search:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (19. 06. 2012) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

where is problem ?

Whole code from com_search (default_results.php)for better understanding:

```
<div class="items">

<?php foreach ($this->results as $result) : ?>
<article class="item">

    <header>

        <?php if ( $result->href ) : ?>
        <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_($result->href); ?>" <?php if ($result->browsernav == 1 ) echo 'target="_blank"'; ?>><?php  echo $this->escape($result->title); ?></a></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="title"><?php echo $this->escape($result->title); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($result->section || $this->params->get('show_date')) : ?>
        <p class="meta">

            <?php if ($this->params->get('show_date')) echo '<span>'.JText::_('PUBLISHED').': '.'</span>'.JText::sprintf('%s', JHtml::_('date',$result->created, JText::_('d. m. Y, H:i'))); ?>
            <?php if ($result->section) echo JText::_('TPL_WARP_POSTED_IN').' '.$this->escape($result->section); ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </header>

    <div class="content clearfix"><?php echo $result->text; ?></div>

</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (19. 06. 2012) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

`19. 06. 2012` is not a date format that PHP's `DateTime` class accepts, see the PHP manual page "[Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)" for the list of formats that are understood.

Comment: Thank you for respond, but i can ask you. how can fix it, because i am total beginner. Only I want set specific date to format on output as I want.

Comment: I don't know Joomla's internal workings, nor care to go look.  I would help with a normal PHP solution but I don't think that is what you are looking for. So, my only advice at this stage is to provide, if possible, a date format that PHP *does* understand.

Answer (score -1):

I've just copied and pasted your new line of into a local hosted copy of Joomla 2.5.6 and it works absolutely fine - no errors at all!

Comment: Hmm, I don't know where is problem, maybe in Yootheme Balance Template, because I modify his com_search and not default com_search in Joomla.

Answer (score -1):

In Joomla this error also happens when one tries to install an extension of any kind, but PHP code cannot write to temp and logs directory.

If one goes to System, System Info and Directory permissions, all shoud be writable. One can change the path to temp and logs directory in the configuration.php or by using Global Configuration menu and System and Server tab.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've never seen a search results error that happened because of installing an extension.  Did you mean to answer a different question?

Answer (score -1):

After four hours spent on Google for this problem, it turned out my cause was unwritable `/logs` and `/tmp` folders.

To verify, follow these steps:

1. Load the following URL (substituting your own domain and hostname):
    `http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_admin&view=sysinfo`
2. Navigate to "owner rights"
3. Check if `logs` and `tmp`are writable
4. If not, you should change the path to those files in your *configuration.php* file.

Here is a relevant quote from the [Joomla forum topic](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=421827QUOTE) that helped me arrive at this conclusion:

> Hello I recently had the same problem, but found the trick!
>
> Log Directory ($log_path) ./logs/ Unwritable
>   Temp Directory ($tmp_path) ./tmp/ Unwritable
>
> The right directory path has to be:
>   Log Directory ($log_path) ../logs/
>   Log Directory ($log_path) ../tmp/